# Running SAGA Processing algorithm from console takes much much longer than from GUI?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, performance, qgis-python-console

I have a road layer with 32000 features, and I want to find all the intersections. when I use processing->SAGA -> convert polygon/line vertices to points, it is all done in less than  5 seconds. However, when I try to do the same thing in PyQgis:

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "temp_points", "memory")
c=processing.runalg("saga:convertpolygonlineverticestopoints",layer,vlayer) # get intersection points
```

it takes about 15 minutes.

Comment: I still have this problem running QGIS 2.18, did you manage to find a way to get an improvement?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Is this still occurring?  What is the latest version that you have tested it at?

Comment: I have not tried this since QGIS 2.18